# One Line of Input to Multiple Variables

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to take one line of input separated by spaces and assign it to four variables.

I read that you're meant to be able to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int i, n1, n2;
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> i >> s >> n1 >> n2;
}
```

For input: `12345 string 4 5` the result would be i = 12345, s = string, n1 = 4, n2 = 5.

But I have to press enter for each variable. I need one line to assign to the four variables.

Comment: Why do you have to press enter for each variable? What happens when you enter them in one line?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I was using -std=c++11 in my terminal and that seemed to be the problem? Before I would try to write my input on one line and when I'd enter, it would ask for another line, but now it seems to be functioning.

Comment: `-std=c++11` is not supposed to change the behavior of this program. There is something else. What happens if you enter `12345 string 4 5` and press return? What's the value of `i`, `s`, `n1`& `n2`?

Comment: @Lachlan: There should be no difference between C++11 and earlier in this regard. Generally speaking, try to make any code sample you are posting self-contained, i.e. enabling us to see the same results as you do, to avoid "it's working now, I don't know why"-situations. This also enables us to show you exactly which code modifications "make it work". See [mcve] which has more rationale toward this end.

Comment: @DevSolar You're right, and I have no idea what changed to make it work. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

This code works already. Compile and run it, and then when the program waits for input just type in:
"12345 string 4 5", enter and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

From [this online CPP tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/):

> Extractions on `cin` can also be chained to request more than one datum in a single statement:
>
> `cin >> a >> b;`
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> 1 `cin >> a;`
>   2 `cin >> b;`
>
> In both cases, the user is expected to introduce two values, one for variable `a`, and another for variable `b`. **Any kind of space** is used to separate two consecutive input operations; **this may either be a space, a tab, or a new-line character.**